# what is the scope of the overloaded operator? Does it affect the insert function for a set that is a class member?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a class defined for a data structure, where I have defined an overloaded `operator<` for the class. However, for the `_positions`, which is a `std::set<size_t>`, the `insert()` function no longer seems to do anything.

I am wondering if the overloaded operator for the class means it is not able to see if a position is in the `set`, and therefore just doesn't add it?

I am able to add/remove to a `map`, but not a `set`. The `kFlags` is a `map` and all those tests pass.

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <math.h>
#include "kmerClass.h"

namespace ft {

KmerClass::KmerClass(std::string kmer)
    : _kmer(kmer),
    _kFlags(),
    _positions(),
    _readIDs()
{
}

std::set<size_t> KmerClass::getKPositions() const {return this->_positions;}
void KmerClass::setKPositions( std::set<size_t> kPositions, uint offset)
{
    for (auto kPosition : kPositions){addKPosition(kPosition, offset);}
}

void KmerClass::addKPosition(const size_t& kPosition, const uint& offset)
{
    size_t kPos = kPosition + offset;
    std::set<size_t> positions = this->_positions;
    positions.insert(kPos);
}

void KmerClass::removeKPosition(size_t kPosition, uint offset)
{
    size_t kPos = kPosition + offset;
    std::set<size_t> positions = this->_positions;
    positions.erase(kPos);
}

bool KmerClass::hasKPosition(size_t kPosition) const{
    std::set<size_t> kPositions = this->_positions;
    const bool is_in = kPositions.find(kPosition) != kPositions.end();
    return is_in;
}

bool KmerClass::operator< (const ft::KmerClass &k) const {return _kmer < k._kmer;}

KmerClass::~KmerClass()
{
}
}
```

The header file is:

```
#ifndef KMERCLASS_H
#define KMERCLASS_H

#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include "ftPropsClass.h"

namespace ft {

class KmerClass
{
public:
    KmerClass(std::string kmer);

    virtual ~KmerClass();

    std::string _kmer;
    std::map<ft::FlagType, bool> _kFlags;
    std::set<size_t> _positions;
    std::set<int> _readIDs;

    std::set<size_t> getKPositions()const;

    void setKPositions(std::set<size_t> kPositions, uint offset = 0);

    void addKPosition(const size_t& kPosition, const uint& offset = 0);
    
    void removeKPosition(size_t kPosition, uint offset = 0);

    bool hasKPosition(size_t position) const;

    bool operator< (const ft::KmerClass &k) const;
};
}

#endif // KMERCLASS_H
```

The test I am trying to run is

```
//======================================================================
TEST_F(TestKmerClass, KPosition)
{
    TEST_DESCRIPTION("Add single position to kmer class");
    ft::KmerClass* testKmerClass = new ft::KmerClass("AAAA");

    testKmerClass->setKPositions({1000, 2340});
    EXPECT_TRUE(testKmerClass->hasKPosition(1000));
    EXPECT_FALSE(testKmerClass->hasKPosition(666));

    testKmerClass->addKPosition(666);
    EXPECT_TRUE(testKmerClass->hasKPosition(666));
    EXPECT_FALSE(testKmerClass->hasKPosition(924357));

    testKmerClass->removeKPosition(2340);
    EXPECT_FALSE(testKmerClass->hasKPosition(2340));
    EXPECT_TRUE(testKmerClass->hasKPosition(1000));
    EXPECT_TRUE(testKmerClass->hasKPosition(666));
}
```

Comment: @Tixii Yeah, because `getKPositions()` makes a copy too. Stop making all these copies! Brush up on "by value" vs "by reference" and such in your C++ book.

Comment: can you recommend somewhere I can read up on it? It is confusing me big time lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with operator overloading, or with `insert`.

You're inserting into the wrong set.

Every single one of the below functions *copies the member variable* then acts on the copy, before discarding it.

```
void KmerClass::addKPosition(const size_t& kPosition, const uint& offset)
{
    size_t kPos = kPosition + offset;
    std::set<size_t> positions = this->_positions;
    positions.insert(kPos);
}

void KmerClass::removeKPosition(size_t kPosition, uint offset)
{
    size_t kPos = kPosition + offset;
    std::set<size_t> positions = this->_positions;
    positions.erase(kPos);
}

bool KmerClass::hasKPosition(size_t kPosition) const{
    std::set<size_t> kPositions = this->_positions;
    const bool is_in = kPositions.find(kPosition) != kPositions.end();
    return is_in;
}
```

Add `&` to make `positions`/`kPositions` references or, ideally, just use `_positions` directly. There is no need for this complexity.

```
void KmerClass::addKPosition(const size_t kPosition, const uint offset)
{
    _positions.insert(kPosition + offset);
}

void KmerClass::removeKPosition(const size_t kPosition, const uint offset)
{
    _positions.erase(kPosition + offset);
}

bool KmerClass::hasKPosition(const size_t kPosition) const
{
    return _positions.find(kPosition) != _positions.end();
}
```

*(I've also fixed some weirdnesses in your function arguments; be consistent about the use of `const`, and prefer by-value for small, primitive types unless you need reference semantics.)*

Comment: Thank you ! 
Not a programmer who has been left on the hook to do revisions for a manuscript :( need all the help i can get !